# umount from all the systems in the lan

Tags: linux, mount, nas

We have some 20 machines in the LAN and 3 NAS boxes mounted on all the devices. I want to permanently umount one NAS box from all the machines. I can do the manual way... SSH to each machine umount the NAS and remove the entry from fstab. Any automated way ?

( I can write a python fab file, but wanted to know if there is any default Linux way.)

Answer (score 0):

There would be a lot of Linux ways and you can write simple bash script and send it to all of your client by `rsync` command and also you don't need edit `fstab` if you don't want permanently un mount it.Command `umount /dev/sd?` will help you.
You can prepare a file that contains your machines IP and you can pass those one by one by using `cat` command to your script.